# Escape "@" character in Blazor

Tags: reference, blazor, mask, implementation, blazor-server-side

Simple question: How to escape the "@" character in Blazor so you don't get reference error in this example?

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@here/harp.gl/dist/harp.js"></script>
```

I already tried "\@" and "\\@"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use double @@.
Docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#razor-syntax)

Comment: well thank you - that was really helpful! "Escape" was the missing keyword here for me, in german it is called "maskieren" (which is mask).